# Link various activities to one SQLite database

Tags: android

Good day fellow programmers, i wrote a small android app in order to practise SQLite database system. The app basically receives data from user and saves it in the table created. But i want to be able to access this SQLite Table from other Activities. ive tried other solutions i saw on this site but it didnt work with my codes. Below are my codes and interface. Thanks so much guys this is gonna help me alot. Thanks.

App UI

[image]

This is for the Table creation

```
db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDatabase", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS database(name VARCHAR,age VARCHAR,gender VARCHAR,email VARCHAR,state VARCHAR,marital VARCHAR);");
```

This for Inserting into the Table

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO database VALUES('" + Name.getText()
            + "','" + Age.getText() + "','" + G + "','"
            + Email.getText() + "','" + State.getText() + "','"
            + MaritalS.getSelectedItem().toString() + "');");
```

Pease Help. Thanks so much guys

Comment: *ive tried other solutions* --> please include them in your question.

Comment: where is your database accessing code??

Comment: Why don't you use your DB class as singleton. Then you can access table from any Activity you'd like!

Comment: in any activity you use the same method as you have to open the database and do stuff

Comment: Please how do i use my DB as a singleton?

Comment: Put all the methods which access or modify your database in a class of its own.

Comment: Thanks so much. great. im really learning alot, im so new into programming

Comment: Yes, but this is not a learning place. You should google for tutorials. Only when you have some malfunctioning code you really can't fix, then this is the right resource.

Comment: @uyioriaghan - see my answer.

Comment: Please do you know any book or video tutorial dat teaches SQLite effectively and comprehensively? bcos i wanna have a gud knowledge of this

Comment: @uyioriaghan See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually we usually place database relevant code to a helper class,we can use it as util method in activities,fragments and other classes wanting to use it.So you just need to create your DBHelper class and place your methods relevant to database in it.

Comment: Please do you know any book or video tutorial dat teaches SQLite effectively and comprehensively? bcos i wanna have a gud knowlodge of this

Comment: @uyioriaghan,if you have learned other databases,like mysql,you can think they are same at most areas,there is a [training](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/) about `Sqlite`,and there is [android training about how to use sqlite in android](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db),I think it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Create the database class in a separate file now create a public function in that class that takes the object as parameter that you want to insert in database 
now in each activity you want to use the sqlite, create an object of database class and call the insert function you created passing the object to inserted

Comment: Please do you know any book or video tutorial dat teaches SQLite effectively and comprehensively? bcos i wanna have a gud knowlodge of this

Answer (score 0):

This is the utility file we use:

```
public class DataBaseConnector {

  private static SQLiteDatabase db;

  private static DataBaseConnector instance;

  public synchronized static DataBaseConnector getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new DataBaseConnector();
    }
    return instance;
  }

  private DataBaseConnector() {

  }

/**
 * Send our query, return our Cursor of results, play with it.
 * 
 * @param query
 * @return
 */
public static Cursor query(String query) {
    if (query != null) {
        openDB();

        while (db.isDbLockedByCurrentThread()) {
            // db in use, keep looping
        }

        Log.d("Query", query);

        return db.rawQuery(query, null);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public static Cursor query(String query, String[] args) {
    openDB();

    while (db.isDbLockedByCurrentThread()) {
        // db in use, keep looping
    }
    Log.d("Query & Args", query + "; " + Arrays.toString(args));
    return db.rawQuery(query, args);
}

public static void execSQL(String sql) {
    if (sql != null) {
        openDB();

        while (db.isDbLockedByCurrentThread()) {
            // db in use, keep looping
        }
        Log.d("ExecSQL", sql);
        db.execSQL(sql);
    }
}

public static boolean canOpenDB() {
    if (db == null) {
        try {
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(GlobalVars.getDBPath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
            if (db.isOpen()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

private static void openDB() {
    if (db == null) {
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(GlobalVars.getDBPath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }
}

public void CloseIt() {
    if (db != null) {
        while (db.isDbLockedByCurrentThread()) {
            // db in use, keep looping
        }
        if (db != null) {
            db.close();
        }
        db = null;
    }
}

public static void StaticCloseIt() {
    if (db != null) {
        while (db.isDbLockedByCurrentThread()) {
            // db in use, keep looping
        }
        if (db != null) {
            db.close();
        }
        db = null;
    }
}

public static boolean isDatabaseIntegrityOk() {
    if (db != null) {
        return db.isDatabaseIntegrityOk();
    }
    return false;
}

public static void beginTransaction() {
    if (db != null) {
        db.beginTransaction();
    }
}

public static void setTransactionSuccessful() {
    if (db != null) {
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    }
}

public static void endTransaction() {
    if (db != null) {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
}

public static String getMaxSize() {
    if (db != null) {
        return db.getMaximumSize() + "";
    }
    return "DB Is Null";
}

public static String getPageSize() {
    if (db != null) {
        return db.getPageSize() + "";
    }
    return "DB Is Null";
}

public static String isReadOnly() {
    if (db != null) {
        return db.isReadOnly() + "";
    }
    return "DB Is Null";
}

public static int releaseMemory() {
    if (db != null) {
        return SQLiteDatabase.releaseMemory();
    }
    return -1;
}

public static String inTransaction() {
    if (db != null) {
        return db.inTransaction() + "";
    }
    return "DB Is Null";
}

public static void insert(String table, ContentValues cv) {
    openDB();

    if (db != null) {
        db.insert(table, null, cv);
    }
}
}
```

To use it:

```
    String sql = "UPDATE L_System SET Value = '" + p.versionName + "' WHERE Setting = 'keyboardVersion'";
    DataBaseConnector.execSQL(sql);
```

**Update**

Tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html